# EZAudio doesnt work: Thread1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS while creating EZRecorder instance

Tags: ios, swift, ezaudio

My complete implementation of `EZAudio`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, EZMicrophoneDelegate, EZRecorderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var recordingAudioPlot: EZAudioPlot!

    private var isRecording = false {

        didSet {

            if isRecording {

                player.pause()
                recordingAudioPlot.clear()
                microphone.startFetchingAudio()
                recorder = EZRecorder(url: filePathUrl(), clientFormat: microphone.audioStreamBasicDescription(), fileType: EZRecorderFileType.M4A, delegate: self) 
                // ** Here is where the error occurs **

            } else {

                recorder.delegate = nil
                microphone.stopFetchingAudio()
                recorder.closeAudioFile()

                player.playAudioFile(EZAudioFile(url: filePathUrl()))
            }
        }
    }
    private var microphone = EZMicrophone()
    private var recorder = EZRecorder()
    private var player = EZAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func startStopRecordingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isRecording = !isRecording
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try! session.setActive(true)

        microphone.delegate = self

        try! session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
    }

    func microphone(_ microphone: EZMicrophone!, hasAudioReceived buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.recordingAudioPlot.updateBuffer(buffer[0], withBufferSize: bufferSize)
        }
    }

    func microphone(_ microphone: EZMicrophone!, hasBufferList bufferList: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>!, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32) {

        if isRecording {
            recorder.appendData(from: bufferList, withBufferSize: bufferSize)
        }
    }

    private func filePathUrl() -> URL {

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first ?? ""

        return URL(fileURLWithPath: String(format: "%@/%@", path, "pathtofile.m4a"))
    }
}
```

The error is following:

[image]
What goes wrong?

Comment: have you checked that all variables are set correctly, especially filePathURL and the asbd ?

Comment: filePathUrl is correct... what is asbd?

Comment: audiostreambasicdescription... second param, in general: you are trying to access an object at a memory address that is not existing in that context anymore... so check which of the various objects is maybe not existent... should be easy to do in xcodes debugger view

Comment: but I get it from example... and it worked there... Look at this here: https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/blob/master/EZAudioExamples/iOS/RecordFile/RecordFile/ViewController.m

Comment: @Volker ok, I will print it within an hour and let you know...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to declare `recorder` as optional type, not an instance:

```
private var recorder: EZRecorder?
```

Something happens when first time it tries to deallocate first initialized recorder... but now there is `nil` so the error doesn't exist anymore.